# Generate math problems

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

**Generate math problems (addition, subtraction, or multiplication) using numbers 0-10. Provide feedback on whether the user was right or wrong and show a score.**

Specifics:

- Must generate addition, subtraction, or multiplication problems
- Numbers used must be 0-10
- Each problem must be equally likely
- If user is correct, must print "correct!" (with the exclamation point)
- If user is wrong, must print "wrong!" (with the exclamation point)
- After providing correct or wrong feedback, must show score with these specifications:

  - Starts with "Score:"
  - Shows number correct and then "correct"
  - Pipe (`|`) separation
  - Shows number wrong and then "wrong"
  - 2 newlines for separation
- Must repeat forever

For counting characters, the [Text Mechanic](http://textmechanic.co/Count-Text.html) counter will be used.

Sample session:

```
1-7=-6
correct!
Score: 1 correct | 0 wrong

9+3=12
correct!
Score: 2 correct | 0 wrong

4*5=20
correct!
Score: 3 correct | 0 wrong

7-8=3
wrong!
Score: 3 correct | 1 wrong

1*1=3
wrong!
Score: 3 correct | 2 wrong

7+6=
```

Comment: can we assume there is only one operator per problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Post-mortem update:**

### Perl 130 bytes

Combining techniques from [dan1111's excellent solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10858/4098) with my own, I was able to squeeze one more byte:

```perl
@b=qw(Score: 0 correct | 0 wrong);$b[$#x=eval^<>?4:1]++while print"$b[@x]!
@b

"x/./,$_=(0|rand 11).chr(41^2+rand 3).~~rand 11,'='
```

There's a few things that might not be immediately obvious. If `@x` is an array, then `$#x` (the largest index of `@x`) will be one smaller than the length of `@x`. In this way, I can use `$#x` to point to the appropriate counting variable, and the length of `@x` to the corresponding message in a single assignment, without having to `+1`. The score string is repeating by `/./`, which will return `1` if an only if `$_` is non-empty.

---

### Perl 131 bytes

Here's my Perl attempt, which is more or less a direct translation of my PHP solution below.

```perl
@r=correct,${_^($n=eval^<>?z:r)}++while@z=wrong,print"@$n!
Score: $- @r | $% @z

"x@r,$_=(0|rand 11).chr(41^2+rand 3).~~rand 11,'='
```

`$-` and `$%` are used for counting variables as they default to `0`, alleviating the need for a `printf`, and at the same time allowing me to combine the `print` statements into one. The score string is not printed the first iteration because `@r` has not yet been defined, and therefore `x@r` (repeat by the length of the array `@r`) repeats the string zero times, resulting in an empty string.

Once again using `chr(41^2+rand 3)` to generate `+*-`, as well as a bitwise xor `_^` to switch between `r`→`-` and `z`→`%`. I would have liked to use a type glob for `*n=eval^<>?z:r`, saving a byte `@$n`→`@n`, but unfortunately typed as a string this comes back as either `*main::r` or `*main::z`, which isn't very useful.

</bandwagon>

---

### PHP 157 (155) bytes

Just to get a smattering of languages:

```php
<?for($X=$Y=+$x=correct;$y=wrong;)echo$q=rand(0,10).chr(rand(2,4)^41).rand(0,10),'=',eval("\${_&\$n=$q^fgets(STDIN)?y:x}++;"),$$n,"!
Score: $X $x | $Y $y

";
```

The initial `$X=$Y=+` is necessary, because undefined variables print as an empty string, instead of `0`. Unfortunate, but still shorter than using a `printf`. One thing to notice is the 'magic formula' `chr(rand(2,4)^41)`. *2^41 = 43* (+), *3^41 = 42* (*) and *4^41 = 45* (-). `chr(rand(3,5)^46)` would also work, but in a different order.

This can be made 2 bytes shorter by using a few binary characters:

```php
<?for($‡=$†=+$x=correct;$y=wrong;)echo$q=rand(0,10).chr(rand(2,4)^41).rand(0,10),~Â,eval("\${~\$n=$q^fgets(STDIN)?y:x}++;"),$$n,"!
Score: $‡ $x | $† $y

";
```

where `†`, `‡` and `Â` are characters *134*, *135* and *194* respectively.

Comment: Perl beats APL! Well done!

Comment: +1, I especially like your use of the while loop to get a single `print` statement.

Answer (score 4):

**Perl, 144 characters**

```perl
@b=qw/+ - * Score: correct 0 | wrong 0/;sub _{print@_;~~rand 11}{_$_=_.$b[rand 3]._,'=';_$b[$x=eval==<>?4:7];$b[$x+1]++;_"!\n@b[3..8]\n\n";redo}
```

Updated (thanks ardnew)

Comment: very nice. you can save 2 chars by replacing `int rand 10` with `~~rand 10` (well technically you should be using `~~rand 11`...)

Answer (score 4):

### APL <s>146</s> 145

In index origin zero:

```
o←'+-×'                          
s←0 0                            
t←'wrong' 'correct'              
l:⍞←(e←(⍕?11),o[?3],(⍕?11)),'=' 
r←(⍎e)=⍎⍞                        
s[r]←s[r]+1                      
(∊t[r]),'!'                      
'Score: ',s[1],t[1],'|',s[0],t[0]
' '                              
' '                              
→l 


10×8=80
correct!
 Score:  1 correct | 0 wrong


2×6=16
wrong!
 Score:  1 correct | 1 wrong


2+5=
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <strike>180</strike> 176

```python
from random import*
r=randrange
a='correct'
b='wrong'
c=w=0
while 1:e=`r(11)`+'+-*'[r(3)]+`r(11)`;x=input(e+'=')==eval(e);c+=x;w+=1-x;print(b,a)[x]+'!\nScore:',c,a,'|',w,b+'\n'
```

[That](http://textmechanic.com/Count-Text.html) counter says it's only 171 chars, but I've counted new lines since that's what we normally do in code golf.

Thanks to [flornquake](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7409/flornquake) for some improvements.

Ungolfed:

```python
from random import *
num_correct = num_wrong = 0
while 1:
    expression = str(randrange(11)) + '+-*'[randrange(3)] + str(randrange(11))
    is_correct = input(expression + '=') == eval(expression)
    num_correct += is_correct
    num_wrong += 1 - is_correct
    print ('wrong', 'correct')[is_correct] + '!\nScore:', num_correct, 'correct', '|', num_wrong, 'wrong\n'
```

Comment: I tried that code in IDLE and nothing happened. EDIT: Never mind, works in a file. +1

Comment: Didn't think of using `c+=x;w+=1-x`, had `c[x]+=1` instead and some string formatting.

Comment: Any Chance of an un-golfed version? Thanks.

Comment: @AriPorad I've added one.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl 154 chars

```perl
$x=correct;$y=wrong;R:$_=join qw|+ - *|[rand 3],map~~rand 11,0,0;print"$_=";$c+=$b=<>==eval;printf"%s!$/Score: %d $x | %d $y$/$/",$b?$x:$y,$c,$.-$c;goto R
```

with some newlines:

```perl
$x=correct;
$y=wrong;
R:
  $_=join qw|+ - *|[rand 3],map~~rand 11,0,0;
  print"$_=";
  $c+=$b=<>==eval;
  printf"%s!$/Score: %d $x | %d $y$/$/",$b?$x:$y,$c,$.-$c;
  goto R
```

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript 169 chars

Here's a solution that doesn't use the console (does that break the rules?) but works via alert boxes (yeah I know...):

```javascript
for(c=w=0;r=Math.random;){prompt(x=~~(r()*9+1)+"+-*"[~~(r()*3)]+~~(r()*9+1))==eval(x)?(m="correct",c++):(m="wrong",w++);alert(m+"!\nScore: "+c+" correct | "+w+" wrong")}
```

The attempts at golfing are quite weak, but this was just for fun right? :)

**EDIT**: Ungolfed version follows. I expanded variable names and split up the assignment of `x` into `a`, `op` and `b`. The logic is the same. Bear in mind that `~~(X)` == `Math.floor(X)` for positive `X`. This is just easier to type.

```javascript
correct=wrong=0;
rand=Math.random;
while(1){
  a=~~(rand()*9+1);
  op="+-*"[~~(rand()*3)];
  b=~~(rand()*9+1);
  x=a+op+b;
  if(prompt(x)==eval(x)){msg="correct";correct++}
  else{msg="wrong";wrong++}
  alert(msg+"!\nScore: "+c+" correct | "+w+" wrong");
}
```

Comment: do you have an un-golfed version by chance? Thanks

Comment: @AriPorad See my edit.

Comment: You can save some chars if you replace the if-else with `statement?(msg="correct",correct++):(msg="wrong",wrong++);`

Answer (score 2):

## K, 155

```
k:l:0;
while[1;
    1@(s:,/(($2?11),(1?"+-*"))0 2 1),"=";
    -1@*$[(.:s)="I"$0:0;("correct!";l+:1);("wrong!";k+:1)];
    -1"Score: ",($l)," correct | ",($k)," wrong\n\n"
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

### **C# - 283 Characters**

This is my solution in C# in 283 characters:

```cs
var r=new Random();int a=0,b=0,x=0,y=0;var w="";Action C=()=>Console.WriteLine(w);for(;;){x=r.Next(11);y=r.Next(11);int[]R={x+y,x-y,x*y};w=""+x+"+-*"[x%3]+y+"=";C();var f=Console.ReadLine()==""+R[x%3];x=f?a++:b++;w=(f?"correct":"wrong")+"!\nScore:"+a+" correct | "+b+" wrong\n";C();}
```

With more indentation, it looks like:

```cs
var r=new Random();
int a=0,b=0,x=0,y=0;
var w="";
Action C=()=>Console.WriteLine(w);
for(;;){
    x=r.Next(11);y=r.Next(11);
    int[] R={x+y,x-y,x*y};
    w=""+x+"+-*"[x%3]+y+"=";C();
    var f=Console.ReadLine()==""+R[x%3];
    x=f?a++:b++;
    w=(f?"correct":"wrong")+"!\nScore:"+a+" correct | "+b+" wrong\n";C();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 90 bytes

Seems like I'm a little late to this question... as is my language, so per site rules, this answer can't officially be selected as the winner. But I had completed my answer for a recent question that was marked as a duplicate of this question and didn't want to let it go to waste, so I modified it a bit for this question.

```
{Bmr3mr"+-*"=Bmr]_o'=o~\~li=:R["correct":C"wrong":W?'!N"Score:"SUR+:USCS'|SVR!+:VSWNN]o1}g
```

Due to the interactive nature of the program, the online interpreter cannot be used. You must use the [Java interpreter](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/).

I normally post a lengthy explanation, but the code works in about as straightforward of a manner as you can get. That's not to say that I banged this answer out in all of a couple of minutes, though, as there was a fair amount of time spent searching for and making small optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell 286

```hs
import System.Random
main=0?0
s=show
a°b=s a++b
r=randomRIO
d=r(0,10)
p=putStr
c?w=do a<-d;b<-d;i<-r(0,2);let{(#)=[(+),(-),(*)]!!i;o="+-*"!!i};p(s a++o:b°"=");r<-getLine;let{u=fromEnum$read r/=a#b;d=c+1-u;v=w+u};p(["correct!\n","wrong!\n"]!!u);p("Score: "++d°" correct | "++v°" wrong\n\n");d?v
```

Answer (score 0):

### VBA - 250

```vba
Sub t()
a=0
b=0
While 1
x=Int(Rnd()*11)
y=Int(Rnd()*11)
o=Int(Rnd()*3)
If InputBox(x & Array("+","-","*")(o) & y & "=")=Array(x+y,x-y,x*y)(o) Then r="Correct!":a=a+1 Else r="Wrong!":b=b+1
MsgBox r & vbCr & "Score:" & a & " correct|" & b & " wrong"
Wend
End Sub
```

Runs until the memory limit for the variables is reached, otherwise it runs 'forever'.